# Duda con lista de inicializadores en C++

Tags: c++, clase

Estoy estudiando `TADs` en `C++`, y en el apartado del constructor llego a la lista de `inicializadores`, está horriblemente explicado y no he encontrado vídeo o página que lo explique claramente.

¿Para que sirve la lista de inicializadores del constructor?

Si en teoría yo puedo asignar valores a las variables en la implementación del constructor, no comprendo porqué(o en qué caso) hay que especificarlo antes.

Comment: En [este vídeo](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-g--AANs9FFUFkyTlRFZ2xfSE0) (apartado de inicialización uniforme) se explican los inicializadores modernos de C++11, no se si es lo que buscas.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster debe estar relacionado pero creo que no es lo mismo, yo no utilizo `initializer_list`

Comment: No me quedaba claro en tu pregunta, pero al re-leerla varias veces me di cuenta de qué hablabas. Habría sido más fácil si hubieras puesto un ejemplo del código que no entendías.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ¿Para que sirve la lista de inicializadores del constructor?

Para responder a esta pregunta, primero hay que aclarar el concepto de "*ciclo de vida*" de un dato.

#### Ciclo de vida.

Un dato existe desde que es [instanciado](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instancia_(inform%C3%A1tica)) hasta que se sale del ámbito en que se instanció, por ejemplo:

```
int main()
{
    int i = 0; // <--- El dato 'i' nace en este punto.
    return i;  // <--- El dato 'i' muere en este punto.
}
```

En el código anterior, la variable de tipo `int` llamada `i` empieza su ciclo de vida al ser definida (`int i = 0;`) y al salir del ámbito en que fue definida (la función `main`) finaliza su ciclo de vida. Veamos otro ejemplo:

```
int main()
{
    int i = 0; // <--- El dato 'i' nace en este punto.

    {
        char c = 1; // <--- El dato 'c' nace en este punto.
    }               // <--- El dato 'c' muere en este punto.

    float f = 2.f; // <--- El dato 'f' nace en este punto.
    return i;  // <--- Los datos 'i' y 'f' mueren en este punto.
}
```

Vemos que los datos nacen cuando se definen y mueren al salir del ámbito en que fueron definidos, en el ejemplo anterior la función `main` tiene un sub-ámbito en que define una variable de tipo `char` llamada `c` que finaliza su ciclo de vida antes de que nazca el dato `f` de tipo `float` porque su ámbito finaliza justo antes de definir `f`.

Esto de los sub-ámbitos es lo que pasa en los bucles `for`:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 0; // <--- El dato 'a' nace en este punto.

    //       v--- El dato 'i' nace en este punto.
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        a += i;
    } // <--- El dato 'i' muere en este punto.

    return 0;  // <--- El dato 'a' muere en este punto.
}
```

Cuando un dato forma parte de otro objeto, su ciclo de vida es el mismo que el del objeto del que forma parte:

```
struct S { int i; char c; float f; };

int main()
{
    int i = 0; // <--- El dato 'i' nace en este punto.
    S s; /* <--- El dato 's' nace en este punto, esto implica que...
                ... s.i, s.c, s.f nacen en el mismo punto. */

    return 0; /* <--- Los datos 'i' y 's' mueren en este punto...
                      ... esto implica que s.i, s.c, s.f tambien mueren aqui */
}
```

Vamos a mirar con más detalle los datos que forman parte de otros objetos, dado que su ciclo de vida empieza al crear el objeto del que forman parte, cuando entramos en el cuerpo del constructor éstos objetos ya existen... de no ser así ¡no podríamos usarlos!:

```
struct S {
    int i; char c; float f;

    S() { // Constructor de S
        i = 1;    // El dato 'i' ya existia antes de entrar en S::S()
        c = 'c';  // El dato 'c' ya existia antes de entrar en S::S()
        f = 0xf;  // El dato 'f' ya existia antes de entrar en S::S()
    }
};
```

Si al enterar en el cuerpo del constructor los datos ya existían ¿Cuándo ha empezado el ciclo de vida?, podemos imaginar que han *nacido* entre la definición del constructor y el inicio del ámbito del cuerpo del constructor:

```
struct S {
    int i; char c; float f;

    S() /* Los datos 'i', 'c'  y 'f' nacen en este punto. */ {
        i = 1;
        c = 'c';
        f = 0xf;
    }
};
```

Una vez aclarado el ciclo de vida de los sub-objetos de un objeto, podemos abordar la pregunta...

#### ¿Para que sirve la lista de inicializadores del constructor?

En ocasiones necesitas dar valor a sub-objetos de un tipo en el momento en que inician su ciclo de vida, esto se conoce como inicialización. Existen ciertos tipos de datos que necesitan obligatoriamente ser inicializados, como las constantes o las referencias, así pues el código siguiente no compila:

```
struct S {
    const int entero_constante;
    int &referencia_a_entero;

    S()
    {
        entero_constante = 1;                   // Error!
        referencia_a_entero = entero_constante; // Error!
    }
};
```

Dado que `S::entero_constante` es un dato cualificado como constante, no es posible modificar su valor cuando ya ha empezado su ciclo de vida. Dado que en C++ no se puede cambiar el objeto al que una referencia está referenciando se necesita asignar valor a las referencias en el momento en que empiezan su ciclo de vida, por ello la manera en que usamos `S::referencia_a_entero` es incorrecta<sup>1</sup>; para solucionar este problema debemos usar la lista de inicializadores del constructor:

```
int otro_entero = 1;

struct S {
    const int entero_constante;
    int &referencia_a_entero;

    S() :
        entero_constante{1},
        referencia_a_entero{otro_entero}
    {
    }
};
```

La lista de inicializadores del constructor también sirve para llamar al constructor de sub-objetos que carecen de constructor por defecto:

```
struct Punto {
    int x, y;

    // Punto carece de constructor por defecto!
    Punto(int a, int b) :
        x{a},
        y{b}
    {}
};

struct Jugador {
    std::string nombre;
    Punto posicion;
};

int main()
{
    Jugador jugador1, jugador2; /* Error! no podemos crear instancias de
                                   Jugador porque Jugador::posición carece
                                   de constructor por defecto y por ello no
                                   se sabe como construir el objeto */

    std::cin >> jugador1.nombre >> jugador2.nombre;

    return 0;
}
```

Fácil de solucionar:

```
struct Punto {
    int x, y;

    Punto(int a, int b) :
        x{a},
        y{b}
    {}
};

struct Jugador {
    std::string nombre;
    Punto posicion;

    Jugador() :
        posicion{0, 0} // Llamada al constructor de Punto
    {}
};

int main()
{
    Jugador jugador1, jugador2; /* Correcto! ambas instancias de Jugador
                                   tienen el sub-objeto posicion inicializado */

    std::cin >> jugador1.nombre >> jugador2.nombre;

    return 0;
}
```

La lista de inicializadores del constructor también se usa para llamar al constructor de la(s) clase(s) base(s):

```
struct Punto {
    int x, y;

    // Punto carece de constructor por defecto!
    Punto(int a, int b) :
        x{a},
        y{b}
    {}
};

struct Punto3D : public Punto {
    int z;

    Punto3D() :
        Punto{0, 0}, // Llamada al constructor de Punto
        z{0}
    {}
};
```

Y (por último) también se usa para delegar la construcción en otro constructor:

```
struct Punto {
    int x, y;

    // Constructor con parametros
    Punto(int a, int b) :
        x{a},
        y{b}
    {}

    // Constructor por defecto, delegando en el constructor con parametros
    Punto() : Punto{0, 0}
    {}
};
```

#### Resumen.

La lista de inicializadores del constructor sirve para:

- Inicializar los sub-objetos del tipo antes de que empiecen su ciclo de vida.
- Llamar al constructor de los sub-objetos del tipo.
- Llamar al constructor de la(s) clase(s) base(s) del tipo.
- Delegar la construcción en otros constructores.

---

<sup>1</sup>Y porque intentamos referenciar de manera no constante un dato constante.

Comment: Más claro imposible, justo eso, gracias.