# Pasar una std::vector por referencia (Evitar Copia)

Tags: c++, c++11

Estoy desarrollando un mini-game las clases involucradas en esta pregunta son:

- PlayState
- IA
- Terrorist.

`PlayState` le da un Vector de Terroristas a `IA`.

```
Intelligence = new IA(terrorists, p->getRigidBody(), _world);
```

La definicion del Vector y del terrorista

```
Terrorist *unTerrorista; 
std::vector<Terrorist*> terrorists;
```

Entonces, yo estoy creando un vector que contiene un puntero a terroristas y se lo doy a `IA`. Lo que yo quiero es que `IA` borre terroristas y se actualice automáticamente en `PlayState` (para evitar trabajar con 2 vectores)

**Información extra:**

**IA.h**

```
class IA { 
public: 
IA(std::vector<Terrorist*> &pTerrorists, RigidBody *pPlayer, OgreBulletDynamics::DynamicsWorld *pWorld); 
IA(const IA& orig); 
virtual ~IA(); 
void updateWorld(Ogre::Real pDeltaT); 
private: 

// int patrullando, rastreando, atacando, muerto; 
bool notifyAllTerrorists; 
Ogre::Real deltaT; 
Ogre::Real auxT; 
RigidBody *player; 
std::vector<Terrorist*> &terrorists; 
OgreBulletDynamics::DynamicsWorld *world; 
};
```

**IA.cpp**

```
IA::IA(std::vector<Terrorist*> &pTerrorists, RigidBody *pPlayer, OgreBulletDynamics::DynamicsWorld *pWorld) {
    terrorists = pTerrorists;
    player = pPlayer;
    world = pWorld;
}
```

Comment: Por favor, los errores como texto.

Answer (score 3):

La `IA` puede, en vez de recibir una copia del vector, recibir una referencia a la `PlayState`:

```
class IA
{
  PlayState& ps;

public:

  IA(PlayState& ps, /* ... */ )
    : ps{ps}
  {
  }

  void BorrarTerrorista()
  {
    if( !ps.terrorists.empty() )
    {
      delete ps.terrorists.back();
      ps.terrorists.pop_back();
    }
  }
};
```

También puede suceder que no desees que `terrorists` sea un vector de acceso público. En cuyo caso necesitas una función que permita eliminar el elemento deseado. Esta solución permite lanzar eventos cada vez que *cae* un terrorista

```
class PlayState
{
  std::vector<Terrorist*> terrorists;

public:

  void NuevoTerrorista(Terrorist* t)
  {
    terrorists.push_back(t);

    // Avisamos de que hay un terrorista
  }

  void BorrarTerrorista(Terrorist* t)
  {
    auto it = std::find(terrorists.begin(),terrorists.end(),t);
    if( it != terrorists.end() )
    {
      delete *it;
      terrorists.erase(it);

      // Avisamos de que hay un terrorista menos
    }
  }
};

class IA
{
  PlayState& ps;

public:

  IA(PlayState& ps, /* ... */ )
    : ps{ps}
  {
  }

  void BorrarTerrorista()
  {
    // Algoritmo para elegir el terrorista a eliminar
    Terrorist* t = /* ... */

    ps.BorrarTerrorista(t);
  }
};
```

Por supuesto siempre puedes pasarle una referencia del vector... pero entonces los avisos para que el resto de componentes funcionen correctamente corre por cuenta de `IA`:

```
class IA
{
  std::vector<Terrorists*>& terrorists;
  //                      ^ Importante!!!!!

public:
  IA(std::vector<Terrorists*>& terrorists, /* ... */ )
    : terrorists{terrorists}
  { }

  void BorrarTerrorista()
  {
    // Algoritmo para elegir el terrorista a eliminar
    Terrorist* t = /* ... */

    auto it = std::find(terrorists.begin(),terrorists.end(),t);
    if( it != terrorists.end() )
    {
      delete *it;
      terrorists.erase(it);
      // Lanzar avisos
    }
  }  
};
```

---

```
IA::IA(std::vector<Terrorist*> &pTerrorists, RigidBody *pPlayer, OgreBulletDynamics::DynamicsWorld *pWorld) {
    terrorists = pTerrorists;
//  ^^^^^^^^^^
```

¿Qué es `terrorists`? ¿No debería ser `pTerrorists`? Fíjate que en mi respuesta yo te he dicho que hicieses esto:

```
IA::IA(std::vector<Terrorist*> &pTerrorists, RigidBody *pPlayer, OgreBulletDynamics::DynamicsWorld *pWorld)
  : pterrorists(pTerrorists)
{ }
```

Cuya alternativa sería:

```
IA::IA(std::vector<Terrorist*> &pTerrorists, RigidBody *pPlayer, OgreBulletDynamics::DynamicsWorld *pWorld) {
    this->pTerrorists = pTerrorists;
```

Comment: Hice exactamente lo que pusiste en el ultimo bloque de código y me esta dando error. Cuando lo paso a IA tengo que indicar algo?, es decir, en esta linea: Intelligence = new IA(terrorists, p->getRigidBody(), _world);

Comment: @Strelok se me olvido una referencia... revisa la respuesta (he añadido un comentario en el último código para que se vea mejor

Comment: Mil gracias amigo, voy a intentarlo.

Comment: acabo de subir una captura del error, porque me sigue dando el mismo error

Answer (score 1):

No veo cuál es tu problema, corrígeme si me equivoco.

Define un alias para vector de terroristas:

```
using terrorist_vector = std::vector<Terrorist*>;
```

Y usa referencia (modificable) en tu objeto `IA`:

```
// Referencia ----> v
IA(terrorist_vector &pT, RigidBody *pP, OgreBulletDynamics::DynamicsWorld *pW)
{
    ...
    ...
}
```

Dado que estás guardando el vector como referencia dentro de la clase `IA`, necesitarás usar la lista de inicialización del constructor para darle valor:

```
// Referencia ----> v
IA(terrorist_vector &pT, RigidBody *pP, OgreBulletDynamics::DynamicsWorld *pW) :
    terrorists(pT) // <---- inicializa aquí.
{
    ...
    ...
}
```

Puedes tener más información sobre por qué es necesario hacerlo de esa manera [en esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/80314/duda-con-lista-de-inicializadores-en-c/80380#80380).

Comment: IA(std::vector<Terrorist*> &pTerrorists, RigidBody *pPlayer, OgreBulletDynamics::DynamicsWorld *pWorld);  Me esta dando error: obj/PlayState.o: En la función `PlayState::initializeIA()':
/home/marcado/Escritorio/HomsOld/src/PlayState.cpp:779: referencia a `IA::IA(std::vector<Terrorist*, std::allocator<Terrorist*> >, OgreBulletDynamics::RigidBody*, OgreBulletDynamics::DynamicsWorld*)' sin definir
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:43: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo 'rendertotexture'
make: *** [rendertotexture] Error 1

BUILD FAILED

Comment: Pon el error en tu pregunta, no en los comentarios de mi respuesta.

Comment: ya subí captura