# ¿Diferencia entre los constructores de C++?

Tags: c++, poo

Buenas, acabé de ver un video acerca de c++ pero está en inglés, hubo una parte en la que empezaba a explicar sobre POO, y habló sobre los constructores, entiendo lo que es, pero hizo dos de los cuales no sé sus diferencias.

Este es el primer tipo de constructor:

```
Jugador::Jugador (int edad, int vida) {
    edad = edad;
    vida = vida;
}
```

Este el segundo:

```
Jugador::Jugador (int edad, int vida) : edad(edad), vida(vida) {}
```

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre los dos?

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Duda con lista de inicializadores en C++](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/80314/duda-con-lista-de-inicializadores-en-c)

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus No estoy de acuerdo con el duplicado. En la que indicas, **no** se menciona para nada `X = Y`, ni su relación (o no) con los constructores ... Relacionada, sin duda. Duplicada, no.

Comment: @Trauma Por eso el comentario (automático) indica "*Posible*". Yo si veo duplicidad.

Answer (score 3):

Hay una diferencia **ENORME**. Tal vez no se aprecie muy bien por el tipo usado (`int`); te propongo este otro ejemplo:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Tipo {
  Tipo( ) { cout << "Constructor por defecto\n"; }
  Tipo &operator=( int x ) { cout << "Asinacion\n de " << x << "\n"; return *this; }
};

struct Jugador {
  Tipo vida;

  Jugador( ) : vida( ) { }
  Jugador( int x ) { vida = x; }
};

int main( ) {
  Jugador j1;      //: vida( ) { }
  Jugador j2( 5 ); // { vida = 5; }

  return 0;
}
```

Verás que hago lo mismo que tú indicas (pero cambiando el órden): llamamos primero a la versión `: XXX`, y luego usamos la asinación.

¿ Cuantas líneas se imprimirán ?

> Constructor por defecto
>   Constructor por defecto
>   Asinacion

- Al hacer `Jugador( ) : vida( XXX ) { }`, **estás llamando al constructor indicado de `Tipo`**
- Al hacer `Jugador( ) { vida = 5; }`, **estás haciendo 2 llamadas**:

  1. Al constructor por defecto de `Tipo` (aunque no lo veas, el compilador lo hace por tí).
  2. Al operador de asignación.

En otras palabras: la expresión `Jugador( ) : vida( ) { ...` **SIEMPRE** se usa; bien explícita por nosotros, bien implícita por el compilador. Y, como consecuencia de ello, **es imposible dejar variables-miembro** sin inicializar.

Teniendo en cuenta lo anterior, es mejor, siempre que sea posible, **utilizar la lista de inicialización** `: var( XX ), var2( XX ), ... {`. Nos ahorramos llamadas a las funciones de asignación, y la llamada a los constructores se va ha realizar de todas formas (queramos o no).

<sub>Nota: hay *truquillos* para dejar miembros sin inicializar si es necesario, pero se sale del ámbito de la pregunta.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Semánticamente ninguna diferencia, es el mismo constructor implementado de maneras diferentes. Las dos expresiones tienen la misma declaración:

```
Jugador::Jugador(int edad, int vida);
```

Entonces, la diferencia está en la implementación del mismo constructor; la primera es funcionalmente equivalente a la segunda, sólo que la segunda es (probablemente) más eficiente.

La segunda forma usa lo que se llama "initializer list" o lista de inicialización. La forma que se prefiere hoy es:

```
Jugador::Jugador(int edad, int vida) : edad{edad}, vida{vida} {}
```

(notarás que se usan llaves en lugar de paréntesis; que es lo que se llama `uniform initialization`).

Como ves aquí se involucran más de un solo tema. Dije que usar una `initializer list` puede ser más eficiente, por ejemplo, aunque un compilador actual probablemente genere las mismas instrucciones para los dos.

Como recomendación, yo te diría que la forma "normal", "esperable", "deseable" de escribir ese constructor es usando `initializer list` junto con `uniform initialization`.